# How to print page by page with cout in C++?

Tags: c++, console, console-application, iostream, cout

Imagine I have this code:

```
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

So in the console, we see the result is printed once until 999. We can not see the first numbers anymore (let say from 0 to 10 or 20), even we scroll up.

[image]

How can I print output page by page? I mean, for example if there are 40 lines per page, then in the console we see 0->39, and when we press Enter, the next 40 numbers will be shown (40->79), and so on, until the last number.

Comment: Better to pipe the output to something like `less` on *nix systems. I don't know what Windows equivalent is. As for not being able to see the first few items, that's a terminal setting and has nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `%` (remainder) operator:

```
for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
    if(i % 40 == 39) {
        std::cout << "Press return>";
        std::getchar();
    }
}
```

This will print lines 0-39, then 40-79 etc.

If you need something that figures out how many lines the terminal has and adapts to that, you could use `curses`, `ncurses` or `pdcurses`. For windows, (I think) `pdcurses` is what you should go for.

```
#include <curses.h>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    initscr();         // init curses
    int Lines = LINES; // fetch number of lines in the terminal
    endwin();          // end curses

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
        if(i % Lines == Lines - 1) {
            std::cout << "Press return>";
            std::getchar();
        }
    }
}
```

This only initializes `curses`, fetches the number of lines in the terminal and then deinit `curses`. If you want, you could stay in *curses*-mode and use the `curses` functions to read and write to the terminal instead. That would give you control over the cursor position and attributes of what you print on screen, like colors and underlining etc.

Comment: thanks for your solution. But I am looking for a solution that works in different OS, with different resolutions. So we can not put a fixed number like this. But as other people said, and as I searched, it seems that we do not have a solution with the C++ code for this problem...

Comment: @trangan "_I am looking for a solution that works in different OS, with different resolutions._" - Ok, that wasn't obvious :-) Well you can use a library like `pdcurses` to create something that will be pretty portable.

Comment: @trangan I added a possible solution for this using `curses`.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked! :) Have a nice day!

Comment: @trangan Nice! Glad it helped and you're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

While the previously answers are technically correct, you can only  break output at a fixed number of lines, i.e. at least with standard C++ library only, you have no way to know how many lines you can print before filling the entire screen. You will need to resort to specific OS APIs to know that.

UNIX people may tell you that, in fact, you shouldn't bother about that in your own program. If you want to paginate, you should just pipe the output to commands such as `less` or `more`, or redirect it to a file and then look at the file with a text editor.

Comment: `|more` works on windows and were on msdos before unix.  from early 80's .